# Dynamic models using ng-if - AngularJS form

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code:

As you can see, this will only get displayed if `q.answer == 'Fail'` - that is the value of a select box further up in the page.

If "Fail" has been selected, then the user can select a defect type which will be saved into `question.failure.type`.

My question is, if a user selects "Fail" and then selects a defect type - and then changes "Fail" to something else. Then `question.failure.type` is still retained, even though the `ng-if` is false now. How can I make it so that `question.failure.type` is no longer in the model if the `ng-if` is false?

```
<div class="panel panel-danger" ng-if="q.answer == 'Fail'">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Comments</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form novalidate name="failureForm">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <select name='defect' class='form-control' ng-model='question.failure.type' ng-options='item for item in defectTypes' required>
                        <option value=''>Select a defect type...</option>
                    </select>

                    ...
```

Edit: added new code as requested

```
<div ng-repeat="q in questions" ng-show="standard.serviceType">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">{{ $index + 1 }}. <span ng-bind="q.questionText"></span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <answer-field question="q"></answer-field>
        </div>
    </div>
    ... then the code in the example above appears
```

Comment: you'll have to handle it wherever `q.answer` is changed, which you didn't show in this snippet.

Comment: So I'll have to handle it in the js code? Not in the HTML?

Comment: that depends entirely on how `q.answer` is bound, which is why I suggested that you add that declaration to the question.

Comment: How do you mean? I don't explicitly bind `q.answer` anywhere in the JS. The HTML is where it's first referenced if that makes sense.

Comment: right, I never mentioned JS code? I suggested that you show how `q.answer` is represented. is it a radio button, a dropdown, a type input?

Comment: Oh sorry, I see what you mean. I've added that to the bottom of the original message. It's a directive - depending on the question it could be a select or text input or number input (or potentially something else but that's all I have at the moment)

Comment: ok, so `answer-field` is some directive that displays what kind of control? this still doesn't show how the user is able to change the value of `q.answer`, or what the valid options would be.

Comment: That's correct. Currently it can be a select box, text input or number input.

Comment: ok, so you should be able to use `ng-change` on the input controls, with a conditional that clears `question.failure.type` unless `q.answer === 'Fail'`

Comment: Oh okay thanks, that sounds like it would work well. How can I do it though?

Comment: also, you can put this code into watch, if you use ng-model in your input

Comment: multiple ways to achieve the same result; but as you can see, they all have the same thing in common, they react to the change of `q.answer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the value of `q.answer` is assigned in an `<input>` element in your HTML, you can clear the value of `question.failure.type` based on any conditional expression using [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange).

For example:

```
<input ng-bind='q.answer' 
       ng-change='question.failure.type =
                 (q.answer == 'Fail' ? question.failure.type : undefined)'
>
```

This is only a trivial example, but it is essentially setting the `question.failure.type` to either the value it already has or `undefined`, depending on if `q.answer == 'Fail'` or not.

Comment: Will undefined make `question.failure.type` not exist at all (which is what I want)? So if I do a JSON stringify of question, I will see no reference to `failure.type` at all?

Comment: that's what setting it to `undefined` does, yes.

Comment: I also assume that this is pseudocode, with the mixed use of `q` and `question`, but hopefully this points you in the right direction anyway.

Comment: this is probably logic that I would consider putting in the controller for the custom directive, or at least in the page controller, rather than inline in the HTML;  This kind of logic is really not the responsibility of the View, but I wanted to show this as a possibility.

Comment: Thanks. I used `ng-change='question.failure = (question.answer != "Fail") ? undefined : question.failure;'` and that worked. But I will do as you say and look at the other solutions too because it might be better suited to the the JS code rather than in-line. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for your question, assuming some predefined values for your scope variable.

```
<html ng-app="myNoteApp">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('myNoteApp', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.q = {
   answer : 'Fail'
 };
 $scope.defectTypes = ['Item1','Item2','Item3'];
}]);
</script>

<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
<form name="myForm">
 <label>Value1:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="q.answer"  ng-true-value="'Pass'" ng-false-value="'Fail'">
 </label><br/>
 <tt>Checkbox value is {{q.answer}}</tt><br/>
</form>
<div class="panel panel-danger" ng-if="q.answer === 'Fail'">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Comments</h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <form novalidate name="failureForm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <select name='defect' class='form-control' ng-model='question.failure.type' ng-options='item for item in defectTypes' required>
                    <option value=''>Select a defect type...</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put in your controller

```
$scope.$watch('q.answer', function(newVal, oldVal){
   if(newVal!='Fail') question.failure.type.length = 0;
})
```

or, put into ng-change method

```
<input type="text" ng-model="q.answer" ng-change="changing()"/>
```

in controller

```
$scope.chaging = function(){
if($scope.q.answer!='Fail') question.failure.type.length = 0;
}
```